# how to create a json object in vb.net 2005

Tags: javascript, vb.net, json

I want to create a json object in vb.net to send the response back javascript function to do something please tell me if anyone have any idea about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you're using .NET 2.0 you have to use the JSON libary by James, with download at [Codeplex](http://json.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=13099) (version for .NET 2.0).

**An example of using Json.NET**

1. Add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json, and an `Import Newtonsoft.Json` in your class.
2. How to serialize an object (Product is only an example object, change this to your own object):

   ```
   Dim product As New Product()
   product.Name = "Apple"
   product.Expiry = New DateTime(2008, 12, 28)
   product.Price = 3.99D
   product.Sizes = New String() {"Small", "Medium", "Large"}

   'Call SeralizeObject to convert the object to JSON string'
   Dim output As String = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(product)
   ```

The `output` variable will hold the value:

```
{
  "Name": "Apple",
  "Expiry": "\/Date(1230375600000+1300)\/",
  "Price": 3.99,
  "Sizes": [
    "Small",
    "Medium",
    "Large"
  ]
}
```

Another example would be to convert an array of strings.

```
Dim myArray As String() = {"Hello", "World"}
Dim jsonString As String = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(myArray)
```

Comment: thank dear but i am unable to implement. please tell me 
about product, what is it, i tried it by making a class but there is some problem so please tell me a little bit more.

Comment: I'm sorry. Product object was only meant as an example, and is not needed. I will edit my answer to clarify this. If you give us the object you need to JSON convert then we can help you implement it!

Comment: okey and thank you so much to reply  me again. here i am describe you what i want to in my json object.
there is 5 columns for each entry like this..
say First enrty   A ["Name", "Age", "Gender", "Location].
    Second Enrty  B ["Name", "Age", "Gender", "Location].
this will go on as the entries will be there.

please tell me .

Comment: hello buddy, now i have a another problem with json, in which format the json object should be returned to javascript function .

Comment: Just try to `Response.Clear()` and `Response.Write(jsonString)` in the codebehind.

Comment: no i was ask that, but its OK, it did it. Thank a lot to help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get access to DataContractSerializer (which is in .NET 3.5) then you can use Json.NET from Newtonsoft. I've used it in the past and found it to be excellent.

http://www.codeplex.com/Json

Comment: ya its okey i find it but how to i use it please me by example, please